# Save loaded RewardedAd for max next 4 hour in SharedPreference

Tags: android, base64, sharedpreferences, admob-rewardedvideoad

i want to save admob loaded Rewarded Ad in SharedPreference and use it for fast show for max next 4 hour. it's possible?
i think it shoud be a data and convert to base64 then save.

Comment: I think you need to read ad-mob policy how can show ad-mob ads without break policy

Comment: i was read it . and they say you can show loaded ad for max 4 hour. i can save loaded ad in application class but android kill it after a few time.